# Set custom view for my location button in google map

Tags: java, android, xml, google-maps

I am using the Google Maps Android API v2, and I need a way to change the view (icon, color, etc.) of "My Location" button.

now i can change the position of that but i need a way to do a full customization.
can somebody help me please?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The location button is actually an ImageView. You should first retrieve the fragment view that is associated with the map:

```
SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                                    .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
```

Next, you should get location view reference from the fragment:

```
ImageView locationButton = (ImageView) mapFragment.getView().findViewById(2);
```

Then change it's image to anything you want. e.g.

```
locationButton.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_location);
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: awesome also locationButton.setBackgroundResource it is also working

Answer (score 1):

I think you can have the "My Location" button view with code below:

```
View locationButton = ((View) mapView.findViewById(Integer.parseInt("1")).getParent()).findViewById(Integer.parseInt("2"));
```

Answer (score 1):

I get the default `ImageView` of the map's my location using `Tag` instead of `Id` to prevent `Expected resource of type id` lint warning -

```
ImageView imageView = ((ImageView)mapFragment.getView().findViewWithTag("GoogleMapMyLocationButton"));
```

Then you can manipulate the `imageView` then.

```
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_custom_location);
```